# Azure SQL Performance/Best Practices: Partitioned Data vs Lots of rows

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

Scenario: multiple customers will all create "Objects" that are stored inside of an "CustomerObject" table.  Let's say it looks like this:

**CustomerObject**:

```
ID bigint
CustomerID bigint
Type int
JSONDynamicProperties nvarchar(max)
```

- Each customer will create somewhere around 50,000 objects.
- There will be around 1000 customers.
- Total objects that the system will need to track is around 50-75 million.
- Read and write operations are split about 50/50

Environment:

- Asp.Net Core
- Entity Framework Core
- Azure SQL

My question is in reference to performance and best practices:

- At what point (if ever) does it make sense to give each customer their own Objects table vs having all objects live in the same table?
- Does having a 1000 or more tables have more of a performance impact than having 50-70 million rows in a single table that everyone is hitting all the time?
- When using Entity Framework Core, can I hydrate a CustomerObject data model using different tables, depending on which Customer is running the query?

Are there any other immediate gotchas you can point out that come to mind?

Thanks for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: With this kind of data model, relational (MSSQL) is probably not the right platform. You're probably better off with HDInsight. But back to relational.... if you partition the table on customer then you are effectively giving them their own table with the advantage that you can access the data  with `WHERE` rather than having to work out the physical name of the table. The downside of using an individual table is the development and maintenance overhead of building a system that needs to know about a new table when a new customer arrives. Maintenance and developmnet complexity has a big impact

Comment: 1: What is the parent of Customer ID in your data model?   For example are customers related in some way such as being part of an organization or group.  2: Also do customer objects have a natural data value that implies the objects expire over time – like a sales date.  3: I would note that the data model you present looks like a no-sql or Document based database as opposed to a traditional SQL db.  There are other non sql server services on Azure and AWS etc. that are designed for these non-traditional SQL Server use cases.

Comment: @SqlSurfer A "customer" is actually an organization.  Each human user is part of a particular organization.  As each user reads/writes objects, they are doing so within the context of their organization, which is the "customer" in the database.  This would be a B2B service.

2. There is a plan to archive stale objects, but the working set is estimated to be around 50-70 million.

3. NoSQL database was considered, but there is a lot of other traditional data storage going on, so it would be best to keep it all in MSSQL if it can work out that way.

Comment: If you wanted to use the Customer ID to group data across about 2 or 3 databases then your application layer could decide at runtime which database to connect to for that customer.  It would give you a way to partition data at the application layer if you found a future need to do so.

Comment: " there is a lot of other traditional data storage going on". Does it have anything to do with these customers? for example do you have other more traditionally designed table which have a foreign key to `CustomerID`?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Azure/SQL Server will likely do better with a different schema.  Effectively you are reading and writing large BLOBs all day with the proposed design, and your performance will likely bottleneck on IO compared to a more optimal logical and physical database design pattern.  (In other words, doing code-first techniques is fast to code and slower to execute in this case).

I will try to answer your basic questions first with the caveat that you likely want to approach this problem differently than you are:

1. Re: 1 table vs. N tables: SQL Server and SQL Azure create query plans and cache them.  The compilation of those plans can be expensive in some cases, so it usually makes sense to have fewer tables with the same schema to reduce compilation overhead in SQL. (You have not really done a schema other than a JSON blob, and the overhead of reading and writing blobs will likely be far from optimal until you also address that in your application).
2. Re: 1000 tables vs. 1 big table:  Assuming you have the right indexing done, SQL can have a table with a seek-for-customer pattern with billions of rows without sweating.  So you don't want the 1000s of tables because of the compilation overhead, but you want to make sure that your queries all seek on something specific enough to avoid IO (logical or physical) so your app will perform well/near optimally.
3. Re: EF + loading from multiple tables: I am no EF expert (I am a SQL expert), but I believe this issue goes away given my answers to 1 + 2.

Now I will try to give you guidance on how to solve your problem more efficiently.  Since you pay for performance in SQL Azure, this should save you money by allowing you to run in a smaller database reservation size.

There are two main patterns you can try, and they depend a bit on whether you have an open schema or a fixed schema.  If you allow customers to create arbitrary values in that JSON blob (open schema), you likely will want to consider a property bag or Entity Attribute Value (EAV) pattern.  This would look like:
CREATE TABLE EAV (CustomerID bigint, Attribute nvarchar(100), Value sqlvariant)
You then would want to create the clustered index on customerid, attribute.

This pattern would allow you to read specific values with index seeks or scan a whole customer's attributes if you need to read everything.  Those values would be roughly collocated on disk and updates will only do IO for data and log for the subset of the attributes you touch.  (NVarchar(max) does support partial writes, but it's likely that EF is going to read and write the whole blob each time if I had to guess how it would be most easily implemented).

EAV patterns are not quite as easy if you want to update many attributes at once since you need to write out N update statements or one larger one with a set of rows to update.

If you have a known set of columns, it is likely better to create a table with columns for each one.  (SQL also has a "sparse" column attribute you can use for largely-null columns).  This allows you to index each field if needed and can allow more complex applications (beyond get-put apps) to perform well.  So, if you wanted to search for customer sales that were on Tuesdays and greater than a certain amount of money, this schema pattern allows for indexing models which make those queries perform well (assuming b-tree indexes are being used).

Please note that SQL Server/SQL Azure also support table partitioning.  For very large tables, you can get management benefits for using partitioning.  However, if you have properly indexed an application like this, you very likely would not need partitioning for the main-line data access performance to be fast since everything can be an index seek.

Hope that helps!
Conor Cunningham
Architect, SQL Core Engine